# kubectl set env from secret

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am trying to set in **VPC CNI (EKS)** both variables

**AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID**

**AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY**

to grab values from a secret. For static values, bellow's command does the job

```
kubectl set env daemonset aws-node -n kube-system AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=MYKEYGOESHERE
```

My question is what's the best practice to bind this environment variable to secrets? Just remembering that VPC CNI is something that comes deployed in your cluster as default.

Is there any way by using a single **kubectl** command? Thanks!

Comment: Best practice is to never use static AWS access keys. Use IAM roles for service accounts: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html

Comment: Yep! You're absolutely right regarding IRSA, but it does not suit me. Being hard limited up to 100 clusters per account is a problem for us. Injecting user's credentials is just one of the approaches we have being trying to :)

Comment: That's not a hard limit, you can request an increase from AWS support

Comment: For using a secret in a env variable, you can use `envFrom`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#use-cases

Comment: Actually it is. If you walk through IRSA configuration, you will conclude that there's a 1:1 relationship of OIDC and cluster. Then check out what is the limit for OIDC per account. . You are restricted up to 100 clusters per account